# Is there any way to install freeBSD from Debian?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation

I know that one can install Debian from (AFAIK) any Linux computer using [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap).

Is there any way to do the same for freeBSD or do I need to make a CDROM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any debootstrap-like software. And there are some (probably solvable) caveats if one was planning to create one:

- There might be file system compatibilitiy issues
- debootstrap's second stage relies on being able to chroot to the target directory as it has to run some apps in it (and the linux kernel can't execute FreeBSD binaries afaik) . Any debootstrap-like freebsd-bootstrapping software would run into the same issue (yes, you can get around this by doing a `--foreign` bootstrap but this just makes stuff more complicated)

However, I can give you some alternatives to burning a CD/DVD:

- Try getting an installed disk image that you write to the partition of your choice
- Install it inside software like VirtualBox. It has support for accessing real partitions/drives, but that's dangerous if you don't know what you're doing. Alternatively, you could install it on a virtual disk and later copy the system partition's contents to one of your real partitions (make sure it's big enough!!!)
- Download a USB pen drive image with the installer on it. You'd just need to copy it to an old unused stick and boot from USB.